# Delete rows that are close to each other more than a specific time and add info about the deleted rows in two new columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, lubridate

I have a dataframe `df1` which summarises detections of different animals over time. The column `Rec` specifies which device detected it (`V4`,`V6`, etc), and the column `Ind` specifies the individual.

I want to remove rows which satisfy the following condition: "there is a detection for the same animal within the previous 55 seconds" (doesn't matter if the detection comes from a different receiver).

Additionally, I want to create these columns:

1) `Num_Rec`: It summarises how many OTHER `Rec` detected the animal in the mentioned interval of 55s.

2) `Which_Rec`: It summarises the name of thes OTHER `Rec` that detected the animal in the mentioned interval of 55s.

If in an interval of 55s the same animal is caught twice by the same `Rec` (i.e. rows 12 and 13 in `df1`), I consider the 2nd row (= detection) a mistake (is not possible that the same receiver catches the same animal twice in 55s) and I don't take into account this row in the columns `Num_Rec` and `Which_Rec` (i.e. in `Result` I don't count `df1$Datetime[13]` neither in `Result$Num_Rec[11]` nor `Result$Which_Rec[11]`).

As an example:

```
df1<-data.frame(DateTime=c("2016-08-01 12:04:07","2016-08-01 12:06:07","2016-08-01 12:06:58","2016-08-01 13:12:12","2016-08-01 14:04:07","2016-08-01 13:12:45","2016-08-01 15:04:07","2016-08-01 17:13:16","2016-08-01 17:21:16","2016-08-01 17:21:34","2016-08-01 17:23:42","2016-08-01 17:27:16","2016-08-01 17:27:22","2016-08-01 17:28:01","2016-08-01 17:29:28","2016-08-01 17:28:08"),Rec=c("V6", "V7", "V6", "V6", "V7", "V7", "V6", "V7", "V7","V7","V6","V6", "V6", "V9", "V7", "V4"),Ind=c(16, 17, 16, 16, 17, 16, 17, 16, 17, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 16, 17))
df1$DateTime<- as.POSIXct(df1$DateTime, format= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz= "UTC")

df1
              DateTime      Rec         Ind
1  2016-08-01 12:04:07       V6          16
2  2016-08-01 12:06:07       V7          17
3  2016-08-01 12:06:58       V6          16
4  2016-08-01 13:12:12       V6          16
5  2016-08-01 14:04:07       V7          17
6  2016-08-01 13:12:45       V7          16
7  2016-08-01 15:04:07       V6          17
8  2016-08-01 17:13:16       V7          16
9  2016-08-01 17:21:16       V7          17
10 2016-08-01 17:21:34       V7          16
11 2016-08-01 17:23:42       V6          16
12 2016-08-01 17:27:16       V6          17 
13 2016-08-01 17:27:22       V6          17
14 2016-08-01 17:28:01       V9          17 
15 2016-08-01 17:29:28       V7          16
16 2016-08-01 17:28:08       V4          17
```

What I want to get is this:

```
Result
              DateTime      Rec         Ind Num_Rec Which_Rec
1  2016-08-01 12:04:07       V6          16       0        NA
2  2016-08-01 12:06:07       V7          17       0        NA
3  2016-08-01 12:06:58       V6          16       0        NA
4  2016-08-01 13:12:12       V6          16       1        V7 
5  2016-08-01 14:04:07       V7          17       0        NA
6  2016-08-01 15:04:07       V6          17       0        NA
7  2016-08-01 17:13:16       V7          16       0        NA
8  2016-08-01 17:21:16       V7          17       0        NA
9  2016-08-01 17:21:34       V7          16       0        NA
10 2016-08-01 17:23:42       V6          16       0        NA
11 2016-08-01 17:27:16       V6          17       2     V9 V4 
12 2016-08-01 17:29:28       V7          16       0        NA

Note1: In `Result[4,]` there is a detection of the individual `16` at 13:12:12 and in an interval of 55s there is another detection (indicated in `Num_Rec`) in the `Rec` number `V7` (indicated in `Which_Rec`).

Note2: In `Result[11,]` there is one detection of the individual `17` at 17:27:16 in `Rec` `V6`, and after that, in an interval of  55s, there are two more TRUE detections, as it is indicated in `Num_Rec` with a `2`. In `Which_Rec` we specify the name of the receivers. In this case:`V9` and `V4`. We have also a FALSE detection in this interval of 55s that starts at 17:27:16. It is in row 13 in `df1` (It is a false detection because an animal can't be detected twice for the same `Rec` in 55s).
```

I would like to know how to do this with a large data frame. I guess it is possible with the package `dplyr`, but I don't know how.

I tried this, as a StackOverflow colleague has proposed in the answers:

```
    library(tidyverse)

    df <- data.frame(DateTime=c("2016-08-01 12:04:07","2016-08-01 12:06:07","2016-08-01 12:06:58","2016-08-01 13:12:12","2016-08-01 14:04:07","2016-08-01 13:12:45","2016-08-01 15:04:07","2016-08-01 17:13:16","2016-08-01 17:21:16","2016-08-01 17:21:34","2016-08-01 17:23:42","2016-08-01 17:27:16","2016-08-01 17:27:22","2016-08-01 17:28:01","2016-08-01 17:29:28","2016-08-01 17:28:08"),Rec=c("V6", "V7", "V6", "V6", "V7", "V7", "V6", "V7", "V7","V7","V6","V6", "V6", "V9", "V7", "V4"),Ind=c(16, 17, 16, 16, 17, 16, 17, 16, 17, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 16, 17))%>%
      mutate(Rec = as.character(Rec),
             DateTime = as.POSIXct(as.character(DateTime))) %>% 
      as_tibble()

First I define a delete_flag by checking if the same individual has been caught more than  once within 55 seconds. Then I filter the data accordingly.
Next I use `pmap` to get `Num_Rec` and `Which_Rec`:

    df %>% 
      mutate(delete_flag = map2_lgl(DateTime, Ind, ~filter(df, DateTime < .x, DateTime >= .x - 55, 
                                                           Ind == .y) %>% nrow %>% as.logical())) %>% 
      filter(!delete_flag) %>%
      select(-delete_flag) %>% 
      mutate(x = pmap(list(DateTime, Rec, Ind), ~filter(df, DateTime > ..1, DateTime <= ..1 +55,
                                             Rec != ..2, Ind == ..3) %>% 
                        summarise(Num_Rec = n(),
                                  Which_Rec = paste0(Rec, collapse = " ")))) %>% 
      unnest()

       DateTime            Rec     Ind Num_Rec Which_Rec
       <dttm>              <chr> <dbl>   <int> <chr>    
     1 2016-08-01 12:04:07 V6       16       0 ""       
     2 2016-08-01 12:06:07 V7       17       0 ""       
     3 2016-08-01 12:06:58 V6       16       0 ""       
     4 2016-08-01 13:12:12 V6       16       1 V7       
     5 2016-08-01 14:04:07 V7       17       0 ""       
     6 2016-08-01 15:04:07 V6       17       0 ""       
     7 2016-08-01 17:13:16 V7       16       0 ""       
     8 2016-08-01 17:21:16 V7       17       0 ""       
     9 2016-08-01 17:21:34 V7       16       0 ""       
    10 2016-08-01 17:23:42 V6       16       0 ""       
    11 2016-08-01 17:27:16 V6       17       2 V9 V4    
    12 2016-08-01 17:29:28 V7       16       0 ""
```

But what I get applying the code you see above is different from what he gets, I don't know why:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 5
   DateTime            Rec     Ind Num_Rec Which_Rec
   <dttm>              <chr> <dbl>   <int> <chr>    
 1 2016-08-01 12:04:07 V6       16      12 ""       
 2 2016-08-01 12:06:07 V7       17      12 ""       
 3 2016-08-01 12:06:58 V6       16      12 ""       
 4 2016-08-01 13:12:12 V6       16      12 V7       
 5 2016-08-01 14:04:07 V7       17      12 ""       
 6 2016-08-01 15:04:07 V6       17      12 ""       
 7 2016-08-01 17:13:16 V7       16      12 ""       
 8 2016-08-01 17:21:16 V7       17      12 ""       
 9 2016-08-01 17:21:34 V7       16      12 ""       
10 2016-08-01 17:23:42 V6       16      12 ""       
11 2016-08-01 17:27:16 V6       17      12 V9 V4    
12 2016-08-01 17:29:28 V7       16      12 ""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a possible solution using `map2` and `pmap` from the `purrr` package.

First, here is the data I am working with:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(DateTime=c("2016-08-01 12:04:07","2016-08-01 12:06:07","2016-08-01 12:06:58","2016-08-01 13:12:12","2016-08-01 14:04:07","2016-08-01 13:12:45","2016-08-01 15:04:07","2016-08-01 17:13:16","2016-08-01 17:21:16","2016-08-01 17:21:34","2016-08-01 17:23:42","2016-08-01 17:27:16","2016-08-01 17:27:22","2016-08-01 17:28:01","2016-08-01 17:29:28","2016-08-01 17:28:08"),Rec=c("V6", "V7", "V6", "V6", "V7", "V7", "V6", "V7", "V7","V7","V6","V6", "V6", "V9", "V7", "V4"),Ind=c(16, 17, 16, 16, 17, 16, 17, 16, 17, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 16, 17))%>%
  mutate(Rec = as.character(Rec),
         DateTime = as.POSIXct(as.character(DateTime))) %>% 
  as_tibble()
```

First I define a delete_flag by checking if the same individual has been caught more than  once within 55 seconds. Then I filter the data accordingly.
Next I use `pmap` to get `Num_Rec` and `Which_Rec`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(delete_flag = map2_lgl(DateTime, Ind, ~filter(df, DateTime < .x, DateTime >= .x - 55, 
                                                       Ind == .y) %>% nrow %>% as.logical())) %>% 
  filter(!delete_flag) %>%
  select(-delete_flag) %>% 
  mutate(x = pmap(list(DateTime, Rec, Ind), ~filter(df, DateTime > ..1, DateTime <= ..1 +55,
                                         Rec != ..2, Ind == ..3) %>% 
                    summarise(Num_Rec = n(),
                              Which_Rec = paste0(Rec, collapse = " ")))) %>% 
  unnest()

   DateTime            Rec     Ind Num_Rec Which_Rec
   <dttm>              <chr> <dbl>   <int> <chr>    
 1 2016-08-01 12:04:07 V6       16       0 ""       
 2 2016-08-01 12:06:07 V7       17       0 ""       
 3 2016-08-01 12:06:58 V6       16       0 ""       
 4 2016-08-01 13:12:12 V6       16       1 V7       
 5 2016-08-01 14:04:07 V7       17       0 ""       
 6 2016-08-01 15:04:07 V6       17       0 ""       
 7 2016-08-01 17:13:16 V7       16       0 ""       
 8 2016-08-01 17:21:16 V7       17       0 ""       
 9 2016-08-01 17:21:34 V7       16       0 ""       
10 2016-08-01 17:23:42 V6       16       0 ""       
11 2016-08-01 17:27:16 V6       17       2 V9 V4    
12 2016-08-01 17:29:28 V7       16       0 ""
```

Comment: Hi again Cett!!! I've been running the code you proposed but R can't do the process. I guess it is because my data frame has 6.582.000 rows. I did a test with only 50.000 rows and it was able to run it (it took around 9 minutes), but if I try with either the whole data frame or 1.000.000 rows R can't do it. I've waited for even 2 days with R running the code. Do you know why? Do you know any solution? Thanks in advance. This is really important. It is for my PhD.

Comment: Best ask a new question where you specifically address the performance issues. Also, make a reference to this question.

Comment: Hi Cettt, If I would add a new row in my df, let's say DateTime= 2016-08-01 17:28:15, Receiver= V6 and Transmitter= 17, I realised that with the scripts you proposed this row would be removed from my df. How should I modify your script to don't delete it? The lapse of time between the row 12 (at 17:27:16) and this new row (17:28:15) is bigger than 55 seconds. I think your script considers that this new row is less than 55 seconds from any previous one, but what I'm interested in is comparing this new row with the first row of that interval of 55 s in which there are several rows.

Comment: Hi, 
the purpose of comments is not to ask follow up questions. If you have a new problem better ask a new question and just reference this question.
See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions

Comment: Thanks Cettt. I followed your advice. Here is a new question to solve my proble: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55900283/how-to-modify-an-r-script-using-purrr-package-in-order-to-delete-specific-rows-t. Could you help me?